# Is it permissible to use the Xcode 3.0 DeRez and Rez command line tools for purposes other than localization?

Tags: command-line, xcode, license

I have an Apple Mac that has Mac OS X 10.5.8. On this Mac, Xcode version 3.0 is installed. From what I can tell, there are also the DeRez and Rez command line tools. The Xcode software may have been installed from one or more DVDs that came with the Mac.

In the Xcode documentation (which can be viewed by launching the Xcode application and then choosing Documentation from the Help menu), there is a page, “Command-Line Tools,” which mentions the DeRez and Rez tools. The path to this page is ADC Home > Reference Library > Guides > Mac OS X > Mac OS X Technology Overview > Mac OS X Developer Tools >. It may be possible to find this page in the Xcode documentation by doing a full-text search over all documentation sets with the search term “DeRez” (without quotes) and the “Contains” option (as opposed to “Starts With” or “Exact”) chosen.

In the “Command-Line Tools” documentation page, there is a “Localization Tools” section. In this section, there is the statement “Table C-15 lists the applications and command-line tools for localizing your own applications.” Afterwards, there is a statement about the directory locations of the tools and then there is a table with information about the DeRez, genstrings, and Rez tools. The description for the DeRez tool includes the statement “You can use this utility to find strings for localization purposes, for example.” The description for the Rez tool includes the statement “You can use Rez to recompile the resource files you decompiled with DeRez after you have localized the strings.” Given these statements about localizing and this categorization of the DeRez and Rez tools, the following question comes up:

Is it permissible under the licensing for the Xcode software and the DeRez and Rez command-line tools to use the DeRez and Rez tools for purposes other than localization (or, put another way, for purposes that do not involve localization)?

I have a software project and there is a resource file (with the .rsrc extension) in the project. For the purposes of this posting, I am using the name `MyGreatProject.rsrc` to refer to the file. One way to edit resources in the file or to add new resources to the file would be to use DeRez to decompile the file into a Rez source file with a command along the lines of `DeRez -useDF MyGreatProject.rsrc Carbon.r > MyGreatProject.r`. (As a side note, when using the DeRez or Rez tools, it would hopefully be permissible to refer to an Apple-supplied Rez type declaration file such as `Carbon.r` in order to make the Rez source file contents easier to understand. The DeRez man page talks about the function of type declaration files. Also, I hope this command line example does not implicate any copyrights regarding the DeRez man page or the Rez man page.) After that step, it would be possible to add or edit or remove resources by editing the `MyGreatProject.r` Rez source file. After that, it would be possible to regenerate the `MyGreatProject.rsrc` file by using a command along the lines of `Rez -useDF Carbon.r MyGreatProject.r -o MyGreatProject.rsrc`. (Once again, I hope this command example does not pose any copyright issues regarding the DeRez man page or the Rez man page.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is definitely permissible.